# MOVAPS accesses unaligned address

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sse, memory-alignment, disassembly

For some reason one of my functions is calling an SSE instruction `movaps` with unaligned parameter, which causes a crash. It happens on the first line of the function, the rest is needed to be there just for crash to happen, but is ommited for clarity.

```
Vec3f CrashFoo(
    const Vec3f &aVec3,
    const float  aFloat,
    const Vec2f &aVec2)
{
    const Vec3f vecNew =
        Normalize(Vec3f(aVec3.x, aVec3.x, std::max(aVec3.x, 0.0f)));

    // ...
}
```

This is how I call it from the debugging main:

```
int32_t main(int32_t argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Vec3f vec3{ 0.00628005248f, -0.999814332f, 0.0182171166f };
    Vec2f vec2{ 0.947231591f, 0.0522233732f };
    float floatVal{ 0.010f };

    Vec3f vecResult = CrashFoo(vec3, floatVal, vec2);

    return (int32_t)vecResult.x;
}
```

This is the disassembly from the beginning of the `CrashFoo` function to the line where it crashes:

```
00007FF7A7DC34F0  mov         rax,rsp  
00007FF7A7DC34F3  mov         qword ptr [rax+10h],rbx  
00007FF7A7DC34F7  push        rdi  
00007FF7A7DC34F8  sub         rsp,80h  
00007FF7A7DC34FF  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-18h],xmm6  
00007FF7A7DC3503  movss       xmm6,dword ptr [rdx]  
00007FF7A7DC3507  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-28h],xmm7  
00007FF7A7DC350B  mov         dword ptr [rax+18h],0  
00007FF7A7DC3512  mov         rdi,r9  
00007FF7A7DC3515  mov         rbx,rcx  
00007FF7A7DC3518  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-38h],xmm8  
00007FF7A7DC351D  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-48h],xmm9  
00007FF7A7DC3522  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-58h],xmm10  
00007FF7A7DC3527  lea         rax,[rax+18h]  
00007FF7A7DC352B  xorps       xmm8,xmm8  
00007FF7A7DC352F  comiss      xmm8,xmm6  
00007FF7A7DC3533  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-68h],xmm11
```

My understanding is that it first does the usual function call stuff and then it starts preparing the playground by saving the current content of some SSE registers (`xmm6`-`xmm11`) onto the stack so that they are free to be used by the subsequent code. The `xmm*` registers are stored one after another to addresses from `[rax-18h]` to `[rax-68h]`, which are nicely aligned to 16 bytes since `rax=0xe4d987f788`, but before the `xmm11` register gets stored, the `rax` is increased by 18h which breaks the alignment causing crash. The `xorps` and `comiss` lines is where the actual code starts (`std::max`'s comparison with 0). When I remove `std::max` it works nicely.

Do you see any reason for this behaviour?

### Additional info

I uploaded a [small compilable example](http://ideone.com/0I4OnD) that crashes for me in my Visual Studio, but not in the IDEone.

The code is compiled in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 (x64 release, v120). I've set the "Struct Member Alignment" setting of the project to 16 bytes, but with little improvement and there are no packing `pragma` in the structures that I use. The error message is:

> First-chance exception at 0x00007ff7a7dc3533 in PG3Render.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.

Comment: What is in `rax` during the crash?

Comment: RAX = 000000CFD296E900 RBX = 000000CFD296E960 RCX = 000000CFD296E960 RDX = 000000CFD296EA90 RSI = 000000CFD2B5C400 RDI = 000000CFD296E910 R8  = 000000CFD296EA98 R9  = 000000CFD296E910 R10 = B5026F5AA96619E9 R11 = 0000000000000286 R12 = 0000000000000000 R13 = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF R14 = 0000000000000000 R15 = 0000000000000000 RIP = 00007FF6CF2D50BD RSP = 000000CFD296E860 RBP = 000000CFD296E9F0 EFL = 00010203 

000000CFD296E8A8 = ????????????????????????????????

Comment: So RAX-58 is not aligned to 16 bytes. Your data structures and types need to be aligned to 16 bytes when using SSE aligned instructions [such as MOVAPS]

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Isn't it dereferencing `rax - 58h` and using that value as the address? That was also my original thought, but I deleted my comment because I thought it was wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's using RAX - 58 as an address. As the lower part of RAX is 900, it makes 958, which is not aligned to a 16-byte address, it will GP fault due to unaligned access. It is rather bad if the compiler doesn't realize this and produces this code "thinking" it will work.

Comment: Are you certain there are no alignment compile flags or "pack pragma's" in the source?  Based on @Mats findings, such directives (esp. on Vec3Base/Vec3f) could be causing problems - nice writeup here: http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html

Comment: Appologies for my bad math above, 900-58 is NOT 958, it is 8A8. However, the "it is unaligned" is still correct. I would argue at this point that producing the smallest possible example that reproduces the problem is the way to go.

Comment: @holtavolt: No alignment pragmas in the code. The project setting for "Struct Member Alignment" is default and after changing it to 16-bit or 8-bit alignment it still crashes. Speaking of pragmas, it may be worth mentioning that I use OMP for parallelization, but the code I am debugging now has been placed at the beginning of main() before any parallelization is started.

Comment: I will try to reduce it to the "smallest possible example" now as @Mats suggested.

Comment: I simplified it a bit and am about to rewrite the question...

Comment: This example is not complete.  It tried to test it with gcc, but it doesn't compile.  (No declaration of `Vec3f`, and you omitted the code you said needed to be there to cause the crash.)  Did you use SSE intrinsics or the `__m128` type at all?

Comment: @PeterCordes, the original question was too long and I got tl;dr responses so I cut it to what I considered important for the problem. I just added a link to uploaded small example at the end at the question. I don't use any SSE explicitly, all was generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc and clang are both fine, and make non-crashing non-vectorized code for your example.  (Of course, I'm compiling for the Linux SysV ABI where none of the vector regs are caller-saved, so they weren't generating code to save xmm{6..15} on the stack in the first place.)

Your IDEone link doesn't demonstrate a crash either, so IDK.  I there are online compile & run sites that have MSVC as an option.  You can even get asm out of them if your program uses `system` to run a disassembler on itself. :P

---

The asm output you posted is *guaranteed* to crash, for any possible value of `rax`:

```
00007FF7A7DC3522  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-58h],xmm10  
00007FF7A7DC3527  lea         rax,[rax+18h]  
...
00007FF7A7DC3533  movaps      xmmword ptr [rax-68h],xmm11
```

Accounting for the LEA, the second store address is `[init_rax-50h]`, which is only 8B offset from the earlier stores.  One or the other will fault.  **This appears to be a compiler bug that you should report.**

I have no idea why your compiler would use `lea` instead of `add rax, 18h`.  It does it right before clobbering the flags with a `comiss`

Comment: A friend of mine tested the example on MSVC 2015 for me and it compiled and worked well, so it really seems to be a bug in MSVC 2013. However, I doubt it makes much sense to report it to MS because it is related to an old product and they sometimes don't fix compiler bugs even within the current version not the old one. Fortunately, I found using AVX instead of SSE to be a viable workaround.